# Show that if $\Sigma_0 = \Sigma_1$ this classifier is linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem, naive-bayes

I have
$Y \in \{ 0;1 \} $
$$
 P(Y=1 \mid X = x)= \frac{1}{ \left[   1 + \frac{\det(\Sigma_0)}{\det(\Sigma_1)} \cdot 
   e^{-\frac{1}{2} \left[ (x-\mu_1)^T\Sigma^{-1}_1(x-\mu_1) - (x-\mu_0)^T \Sigma^{-1}_0(x-\mu_0)\right]}   \right] }
$$
$P(Y=0 \mid X = x)$ is the same as $P(Y=1 \mid X = x)$ but where you switch the indices $0$ and $1$

If  $ \Sigma_0 =\Sigma_1$ how can I show that the classifier defined by $\operatorname{argmax} \{P(Y=y\mid X=x)\}$ is linear in $x$?

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks for the edit, even though I am not sure what you changed?

Comment: You shouldn't exclude the "equals" sign in $\text{“} \Sigma_0 = \Sigma_1\text{''}$ from what appears within MathJax. It causes a mismatch in font sizes and lack of proper spacing. If you're going to use LaTex without looking like someone who can't spell, you should get used to these things. Especially since it's simpler when done correctly.

Comment: Also, notice the difference between $det A,$ coded as `det A`, and $\det A,$ coded as `\det A`. This not only prevents italicization, but results in context-dependent spacing, so the space to the right of $\det$ is different in $\det A$ from what it is in $\det(A),$ and you get proper spacing in things like $3\det(A),$ which looks different from, for example, $3\text{det}(A). \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Okay, nice! Good to know. Can you also help me with my initial question or is it only shaming for being new to LaTex?

Comment: I'm not trying to shame anyone. Maybe I can help with the question, but that will take somewhat longer.

Comment: @MichaelHardy  sorry Michael if you didn't mean it, but I just felt it that way. and it is not the first time. I am just trying to do the right thing and I am happy to learn and try my best to be a "good citizen". Thanks for your understanding

Comment: The displayed expression is a monotone function of $(x-\mu_1)^T \sum^{-1}_1 (x-\mu_1) - (x-\mu_0)^T \sum^{-1}_0(x-\mu_0),$ so you only need to look at the way in which that depends on $x.$ Is there some scalar-valued linear function of $x$ that is a monotone function of that? $\qquad$

Comment: If you want to use a capital sigma in a context that doesn't involve summation, use ```\Sigma```, not ```\sum```.

Comment: $\ldots\,$ or $(x-\mu_1)^T \Sigma^{-1}_0 (x-\mu_1) - (x-\mu_0)^T \Sigma^{-1}_0(x-\mu_0). \qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
& (x-\mu_1)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu_1) - (x-\mu_0)^T \Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_0) \\[8pt]
= {} & (x-\mu_1)^T \Sigma^{-1} (\mu_0-\mu_1) + (x-\mu_1)^T\Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu_0) - (x-\mu_0)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu_0) \\[8pt]
= {} & (x-\mu_1)^T \Sigma^{-1} (\mu_0-\mu_1) + \Big((x-\mu_1) - (x-\mu_0) \Big) \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu_0) \\[8pt]
= {} & (x-\mu_1)^T \Sigma^{-1} (\mu_0-\mu_1) + (\mu_0 - \mu_1)\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu_0)
\end{align}

Each term above is a scalar and thus equal to its transpose, and also $\Sigma^{-1}$ is its own transpose; thus this is equal to
$$
(\mu_0-\mu_1)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu_1) + (\mu_0-\mu_1)\Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu_0).
$$
This is a scalar-valued function that is <s>linear</s> affine in $x$ (i.e. linear plus constant).

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy , but Isn't it still in the exponential? which is not linear?

Comment: @lalaland : The point is there is a scalar-valued function that is linear in $x$ for which we can say $\Pr(Y=1\mid X=x) > \Pr(Y=0\mid X=x)$ if that function is on one side of a certain boundary, and that inequality gets inverted if it's one the other side. The probability itself as a function of $x$ is of course not linear. $\qquad$

Comment: so it all has to do with the "distance" of x from $\mu_1$ and $\mu_0$. That's your boundary, right?

Comment: @lalaland : Not if taken literally. There is a scalar-valued linear function that can be evaluated at $x,$ at $\mu_0,$ and at $\mu_1,$ and the decision is determined by the distance between the value of that function at $x$ and its values at $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1. \qquad$

Comment: For example, if this is in a $3$-dimensional space, there is a plane on whose two opposite sides one finds $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1,$ and one makes one decision if $x$ is on one side of that plane and the other decision if it's on the other side.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I appreciate it